# Python en Nevim

Tags: linux, neovim-plugin

I am on arch linux with qtile, and I want to use a neovim UltiSnip plugin but no matter how much I install python, neovim does not recognize

I am on arch linux with qtile, and I want to use a neovim UltiSnip plugin but no matter how much I install python, neovim does not recognize hello